# using ng-options with a response object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been through numerous answers about how to use ng-options but haven't found a solution or a right way to do it.

My code is simple. I wanted to iterate through the response object I received and populate my "select" tag's 'options' with the name property.

index.js

```
app.controller("promo", function($scope, $http) {

$scope.behaviors = {};

$scope.init = function() {
    return $http.get('/behaviors').then(function(response) {
         $scope.behaviors = response.data;
         console.log(typeof($scope.behaviors))
    })
}
```

My response looks like this

```
Object {bangalore.yml: Object, ean.yml: Object, chennai.yml: Object}
```

I thought I could do it with ng-repeat like so

```
<select ng-model="behavior" ng-repeat="behavior in behaviors">
<option>{{behavior.name}}</option>
```

I'm a beginner and I need to know what to do and how ng-options really works.

Comment: where is the name field in your response "behavior.name" ? Sorry but i couldn't get your response properly can you provide more info about it ?
And ng-repeat will be apply on <option> not on <select> or else use ng-options

Comment: each object i.e "bangalore.yml" has properties html, location and name.

Comment: Ping check my answer hopt it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :-

```
 <select ng-model="behavior" ng-options=" value.name for (key, value) in behaviors">

      </select>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AKv2csROU3I8YeW3DXDr?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! It works. Could you please explain how it works?

Comment: You have a object response which is assigned to $scope.behaviors.So,by using ng-option you can extract the key and value of each element keys are ['bangalore.yml','ean.yml','chennai.yml'] and values are again objects which consist name,location,etc. So in ng-options we extract each value and assigned value.name to each option.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, use ng-options:

```
<select ng-model="behavior" ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in behaviors">
```

This binds the selected value to `behaviour`, and the display options will be the keys of your object.
Also notice you don't need the `option` element.

Comment: This sort of worked. It now shows me the "bangalore.yml, chennai.yml and ean.yml". I however, need the name property in each of these objects to be displayed. Do you know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

If you want to show name and bind whole object then use below

```
<select ng-model="behavior" ng-options="behavior.name for behavior in behaviors"></select>
```

If you want to show name and bind id of that object then use below

```
<select ng-model="behavior" ng-options="behavior.is as behavior.name for behavior in behaviors">
</select>
```